# peugeot partner 2002

Tags: engine, troubleshooting

My peugeot partner engine is shaking and loosing power /cuting out the shuddering is quite violent and when I drove it the short distance to home the engine got very hot and smoky

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a diesel:

- If it's grey smoke, stop driving it and get the Turbo fixed
- If it's blue smoke, time for a valve cleaner or more likely a valve grinding operation.